# Workmail Lambda Permissions denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-workmail

I am trying to understand why I cannot call my lambda from AWS Workmail. I obviously have not setup the correct permissions. I am struggling to understand where I am falling short.

```
One or more inputs was invalid: Cannot call lambda arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:006640600424:function:toi-ordering-script due to permission denied. Check that WorkMail is authorized to call your function and that the function exists. Read more.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you haven't given [permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html#permissions-resource-serviceinvoke) to Workmail to invoke your function, or they are given incorrectly.

You can add such permissions using AWS CLI's [add-permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/add-permission.html). For example:

```
aws lambda add-permission \
    --function-name toi-ordering-script \
    --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
    --statement-id workmail \
    --principal workmail.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

You may need to modify it to your specific settings.

Comment: Does this need to be done via the CLI or does AWS have something internal that I can use?

Comment: @MatthewMetros Hi. If the service appears in triggers in lambda console, then you don't need to use CLI. If its not in triggers, I think CLI or SDK are the only options.

Comment: It is not in triggers :(

Comment: @MatthewMetros Maybe Workmail console has some option for that. Sadly, I don't use Workmail, so I'm familiar with its console functionality.

Comment: @MatthewMetros This is setting a resource permission which is what you need not a trigger. Resource permissions are there in the console.